# Transmission spectrum of optical cavities

Tags: optics, resonance, laser-cavity

Why is the transmission spectrum of a Fabry-Perot (FP) cavity looks different to that of a ring resonator? i.e. at resonances in FP we have transmission peaks at resonances whereas in rings there are dips. I would like to know this from a physical view-point. Any help would be appreciated as I am relatively new to the field.

If rings have dips at resonant frequencies then what are the advantages of using a ring resonator at resonance because there isn't any transmission at those points?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community What exactly do you consider unclear here? In my view, this question is perfectly well defined.

Answer (score 0):

The FP cavity and the microresonator actually work in very similar ways. In both cases, when the input laser on on resonance then the light gets into the cavity. If you look at the *reflection* from the FP cavity, then you will see a dip in the signal when the laser is on resonance. When you look at the through port of a microresonator you are seeing the light that does not enter the cavity, equivalent to the reflected light of the FP cavity. If you look at the drop port, then you will see the equivalent to the transmitted light from the FP cavity.
[image: microresonator ports]